# Passing a list in shell script

Tags: python, bash, list, shell

This is the first time I am working with shell scripts. Passing one element at a time works. However I have got confused because I have a method which requires a list as an argument and currently, whatever I tried, it just takes the first element of list. But I wish to pass the entire list at one time only.

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
list = 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9 0.95;
qsub job.sh "label" $list
```

job.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python file.py $1 $2
```

file.py

```
import sys
import os
from myClass import myClass
label = sys.argv[1]
list = sys.argv[2]
myObject = myClass(label,list)
```

Comment: You should be able to slice `sys.argv` -- in other words, something like `lst = sys.argv[2:]` (try to avoid using `list` though).

Answer (score 3):

You need to double quote things with spaces in the shell, and drop spaces around assignments (=)

```
list="0.1 0.2 24 45"
qsub job.sh "label" "$list"
```

and

```
python file.py "$1" "$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

job.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python file.py $*
```

file.py

```
import sys
import os
from myClass import myClass
label, list = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:]
myObject = myClass(label, list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I forgot to mention that I have other arguments in the method. By doing $*, it is considering other arguments as well as a part of the list. How should I tackle this..

Comment: If your example does not demonstrate what you are asking, noone can help. Trim down the ridiculously long list of numbers (which are not required for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show a better example.

Comment: Ok...see revisions

Comment: ./run.sh: line 12:  syntax error near unexpected token `list'                                           
./run.sh: line 12: `list = 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9 0.95;'

Comment: I am getting the above errors. Should I make any changes to run.sh script?

Comment: You REALLY need to simplify your example. Why are there so many numbers? And why is there a semicolon on the end of the line?  Stop and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve